# ASP.NET MVC5 EF6: Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'User_AppUser_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state. Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, asp.net-identity-2

I have an MVC5 project using Identity 2 and Entity Framework 6 and the repository pattern, that is redeveloping an old classic asp system.
I started the project with Identity 1, after which in v2 they introduced that the ApplicationUser primary key can be anything, not just a GUID.

However, I have already mapped the ApplicationUser (AspNetUsers table) to my existing User table from the old project as a 1:1 relationship (as much as EF can). It is really a 1:1 which was necessary because my old table has many many fields.

**When I try to delete a User, and it's associated ApplicationUser, I get the following error:**

> A relationship from the 'User_AppUser' AssociationSet is in the
>   'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding
>   'User_AppUser_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

**Here is the Application User:**

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {                
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);             
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

**Here is the User**

```
public class User : BaseModel
{        
    // The new identity system has a Guid as Id that is different to the UserId, So on the AspNetUser table there is new UserId field mapped.
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }    
    public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }      
    public string UserLogin { get { return AppUser.UserName; } }
    public string UserPass { get { return AppUser.PasswordHash; } }
    public string EmailAddress { get { return AppUser.Email; } }

    //.....ETC ....//
}
```

**Here is the mapping:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()                
            .HasRequired(e => e.AppUser)                
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.User)
            .Map(c=>c.MapKey("UserId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

**Here is the applicationUser table (AspNetUser)**
I have a foreign key mapping to the User table:

1. Id nvarchar(128)
2. UserName varchart(256) etc..
3. UserId int - *maps to User Table: UserId int*

**And here is the deleting code:**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([Bind(Include="Id")] UserSaveViewModel viewModel)
{            
    ApplicationUser appUser = UserManager.FindById(viewModel.Id);                        
    await UserManager.DeleteAsync(appUser);                        
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { isUserDeleted = true });
}
```

I have also tried this instead of UserManager.DeleteAsync()

```
var user = appUser.User;
await _repository.DeleteAsync<User>(user); //using the repository pattern
```

But that gives this error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

How can I get this to cascade delete correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot map a 1:1 relationship this way.  The only way EF supports 1:1 mapping is with a shared primary key, which means both tables have to have the same key, and one has to be a foreign key to the other.

It's unfortunate, but it's a holdover from the time when EF did not support unique constraints, and you cannot have a 1:1 mapping without a shared primary key without using a unique constraint.  When EF 6.1 added Unique index support, the internal logic was never updated to fully support 1:1 scenarios.

Comment: @RhysStephens - Well, you could make the primary key of User the same as ApplicationUser.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations  You could also make it a 1:Many and put a unique index on it, making it effectively 1:1 but you will still have to treat one side with many semantics.

Comment: Sorry, I've read the article but it doesn't make sense to me. They are referring to 3 objects, me just 2. 
The relationship works when I **create** new Users: `var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = vm.UserLogin, User = newUser, Email = vm.EmailAddress };
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, vm.Password);`. Just not on Delete.

Comment: @RhysStephens - where did "UserReviewNotes" come into this?

Comment: Sorry. I meant:             
             `modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.AppUser)
                .WithRequired();`

Comment: @RhysStephens - You can't just change the mapping.. you have to change the primary keys to use a shared key, making sure they're the same type, and that the dependent type is non-generated key..

Comment: I don't understand how I can do that with code-first